# Using Centos to sign .deb packages

Tags: debian, centos, apt, repository, gpg

When installing a package using `apt-get install`, the package is installed but gives the following warning:

```
W: GPG error: http://12.345.67.890/repo stretch InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: 789B6B7630E9396A52F4D467B646B1C0B99B99E4
W: The repository 'http://12.345.67.890/repo stretch InRelease' is not signed.
```

Situation:

1. I am the maintainer of the repository, and don't wish users to need
   implement workarounds on their side.
2. The repository is being hosted on Centos7.
3. reprepro.x86_64 4.17.0-3.el7 from epel is being used.
4. The receiving machine is a RPi3.
5. Both machine's `date` show identical times.

Steps taken (mostly from [SetupWithReprepro](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/SetupWithReprepro) )

1. I generated GnuPG keys using default values and a passphrase.
2. I configured Apache
3. I configured reprepro

   - The Maintainer in repo/dists/stretch/main/binary-armhf/Packages lists the same name and email as was used with my GPG key.
   - In conf/distributions, I've used "SignWith: default" as well as my main public and secondary public key, but no change.  Note that the user I've implemented under has only one GPN key.
4. I did not use overrides.
5. I added packages to the repository
6. I exported the public GnuPG key

   - I've tested using both the main public and secondary public key, and they produce an identical key.
7. I did not attempt to sign the Debian package using dpkg-sig as everything I've read states reprepro will automatically do so.
8. I imported the public GnuPg key described by Step 6.

What can I do to prevent this warning?  If no single answer, I also have sub-questions:

1. Can the issue be related to installing on Centos7?
2. Is the package’s changelog file the same as repo/dists/stretch/main/binary-armhf/Packages?
3. Does my key somehow have to be sign or hosted by someone else due to web of trust?
4. Do I need to also insert my email when exporting the public GnuPg key (i.e. step 6 above)?  If so, how?
5. How can I manually ensure the key is properly signed on a different machine?
6. Is `dpkg-sig` or equivalent available for Centos7?
7. Does `dpkg-buildpackage` also need to be used?  It isn't referenced by [SetupWithReprepro](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/SetupWithReprepro) .

Comment: I think you want to sign the repo and not the packages.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro  Sorry, bad wording on my side.  Yes, the repo is what I signed (or actually what `reprepro` is suppose to automatically sign).

Comment: Add the epel repo (download the epel rpm for setting this up), then add these deb compat packages:

`sudo yum install dpkg dpkg-devel gnupg2 perl-TimeDate`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro  The folowing is already installed: `dpkg.x86_64`, `dpkg-dev.noarch`, `dpkg-devel.x86_64`, `dpkg-perl.noarch` (all from 1.17.27-1.el7 @epel), `gnupg2.x86_64` (from 2.0.22-4.el7 @base), `perl-TimeDate.noarch` (from 1:2.30-2.el7 @base)

Comment: See [Building an apt repository on CentOS](https://bgstack15.wordpress.com/2016/06/22/building-an-apt-repository-on-centos/)

Comment: Asked and answered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387053/ , I suspect.

Comment: @JdeBP  Yes, it seems it has been asked... and answered.  Prior to posting this question, I searched for quite a bit and didn't come across it.  Thank you!  Wish I found it earlier and saved the time coming up with theoretical causes...

Comment: Note that the "existing question" does not have a selected answer.  I've been trying to verify whether it will solve the problem, however, have not yet been successful.