# Debian 8 Jessie errors on all MariaDB mirrors : Signature by key 199369E5404BD5FC7D2FE43BCBCB082A1BB943DB uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)

Tags: debian, apt, gpg, mariadb

I've inadvertently stepped into "update hell".

I updated a number of dependencies trying to install the Gerbera media server. In the process several existing services stopped running, including mariadb.

Then, when I tried to update/upgrade my mariadb install I hit the following error on the UKFast mirror I had been using:

```
apt-get update
...
Err:4 http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/mariadb/repo/10.3/debian jessie InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: 199369E5404BD5FC7D2FE43BCBCB082A1BB943DB
Reading package lists... Done
```

now, i've tried several recipes for updating GPG keys, including installing the debian-archive-keyring package. I also switched to a different mirror for mariadb, but still the same error:

```
GPG error: http://mirrors.coreix.net/mariadb/repo/10.2/debian jessie InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: 199369E5404BD5FC7D2FE43BCBCB082A1BB943DB
```

Searching the web for clues I'm beginning to think this is actually a problem with the way the mirror has their content signed, per this posting- [Debian 9, APT, and "GPG error: ... InRelease: The following signatures were invalid:"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387053/debian-9-apt-and-gpg-error-inrelease-the-following-signatures-were-inva)

assuming this is the problem (the mirrors using obsolete SHA1 signatures), until the mirrors update their sigs, is there a way for me to persuade apt to process the package?

### UPDATE

This seems to have been caused by my choosing an incorrect / unsupported combination of version names.

After trying a lot of combinations, I ended up using the following in /etc/sources.list.d/mariadb.list:

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://mirrors.coreix.net/mariadb/repo/10.3/debian stretch main
deb-src http://mirrors.coreix.net/mariadb/repo/10.3/debian stretch main
```

Now Stretch isn't my current version (I'm on Buster), but I'm guessing Stretch is the latest release supported by MariaDB.

I'm wondering of the key error was a red herring, but at least it works now, without any further updates to the release keys.

Thanks to those who responded with suggestions.

Comment: You can always ignore signatures, at least temporarily

Comment: Maybe temporarily switch to another mirror before allowing in packages with an invalid signature and wait until it's fixed. You should be able to change it in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. But you should back it up before changing.

Comment: You mention Debian 8.  My question talked about Debian 9.  You can clarify the question by [edit]ing in the version of APT that you have upgraded to.  (-:

Answer (score 2):

The key did change between Jessie and Stretch. For Stretch, you would use:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common dirmngr
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386,ppc64el] http://mirrors.coreix.net/mariadb/repo/10.3/debian stretch main'
```

For Jessie, you would use:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386,ppc64el] http://mirrors.coreix.net/mariadb/repo/10.3/debian jessie main'
```

> Our repositories for Debian "Sid" and the Ubuntu 16.04 and beyond "Xenial" use a new GPG signing key. As detailed in [MDEV-9781](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9781), APT 1.2.7 (and later) prefers SHA2 GPG keys and now prints warnings when a repository is signed using a SHA1 key like our previous GPG key. We have created a new SHA2 key for use with these affected repositories.

Comment of [the mariadb release manager](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9781?focusedCommentId=84350&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-84350):

> Yes, there will be a Stretch repository eventually. It will use the same key we're now using for Sid.

See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/gpg/ as well as the repo configuration tool at https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories